# Force invisible text fields to have a value of "0" or ""

Tags: jquery, forms, hide, show, invisible

I know this is kind of cludgey, but I am so close to a solution that I had to post this.

I have a form with two checkboxes that toggle whether or not the relevant spans are visible. num_bw and num_c are spans that contain input boxes where the user puts how many of the two types of products the user wants. I am worried, though, that the user might put a number into a text field that's temporarily visible (say the first one, in the num_bw span), but then would change his mind and uncheck that check box and put a number into the box in the num_c span instead.

The way this code works, the num_bw field would now be invisible- but it could **still contain a number!** If he hits submit, the user might be surprised to see that those 3 black & white products he no longer wants are still in his shopping cart! Woops!

So I need to check if any of these two text fields (their names are orderquantitybw and orderquantityc, I can also add ID's if I need to) are in a span which is now invisible (#num_bw and #num_c), and if they are, to turn their value to nothing, zero, zilch, "", whatever won't confuse the shopping cart software (which isn't my department, how it works is a tad opaque to me.)

This is in the head, it just makes these spans invisible at the start:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#num_bw').hide();
    $('#num_c').hide();
    });
```

This is right after the form in question, it makes the spans visible or invisible when the user clicks on the checkboxes:

```
$('#show_c').click(function(){
$('#num_c').toggle();
});
$('#show_bw').click(function(){
$('#num_bw').toggle();
});
```

And I want to add a function to the end. I stopped just short of writing it. Any help?

```
    $('#submit_btn').click(function(){

    /*Insert script to turn form box's values to "0" if 
    they are in an invisible span*/

    )};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function(){

    $("#num_bw, #num_c").each(function(){
       if(!$(this).is("visible")){
         $(this).find("input").val("0")
       }
    });

)};
```

Comment: Hmm. I wonder. Shouldn't It be    if(!$(this).is("invisible")){  instead?

Comment: Your comments says /*Insert script to turn form box's values to "0" if 
    they are in an invisible span*/ so if(!$(this).is("visible")) will check for span which is not visible.

Comment: that blows my mind a little bit. I have a lot to learn but I trust you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function(){
    $("#num_bw, #num_c").filter(':hidden').find('input').val('0');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#num_bw:hidden").val(0)
$("#num_c:hidden").val(0)
```

should do it.  Or you could do something like this:

```
$(".quantityTextBox:hidden").val(0)
```

for textboxes with the class "quantityTextBox"